# How to delete Selected item on treeview with database

Tags: python-3.x, database, tkinter, treeviewitem

How to delete Selected item on treeview with database

Code:

```
def delete():
 selected_item = self.Scrolledtreeview1.selection()[0]
 conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',username='root',password='root',database='mydatabase')
 mycursor = conn.cursor()
 sql_select_Query = ("DELETE FROM data WHERE id = %s")
```

Comment: What is the problem here? isnt there a syntax error in your sql command?

Comment: You didn't format a variable in the query. "%s" is probably not a valid id.

Comment: Ive added an answer, if it helped, make sure to mark it as the answer so i can mark the Q as closed

Comment: It really depends on whether the result of `self.Scrolledtreeview1.selection()[0]` is the `id` of a record in the database.  Also what placeholder is used in the SQL statement depends on the database engine used.